# How to find stability of a third order non-linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

Suppose we have a third order system, reduced to three first orders in the form

$\dot x_1 = x_2 \\
\dot x_2 = x_1 + x_3F(x_1) \\
\dot x_3 = x_3F(x_1)$

Suppose we know $F(0) = 0$

How do we find the stability around the equilibrium point?

My guess was to try and use Lyupunov but I am having trouble seeing how it works. I believe the only equilibrium point is $x = 0$, but I am lost where to go from here. If the system was second order, I could use phase portraits, is there something similar for third order?

Also, there seems to be a lack of resources on this material, any suggestions would be helpful!

Thank you

Comment: Where is this problem from? Is anything else known about $F$? It is possible to reduce it to $$x_1'' = x_1 + \exp\left(\displaystyle \int F(x_1) dx_1\right) F(x_1)$$ I am not sure if that is useful yet.

Comment: @Moo This problem is similar to a homework problem I have, but I have changed it because I want to know the process for how to do these problems not just solve the homework. The only other thing known about $F$ is that  $F(h)h > 0$ for $h \neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

An equilibrium point requires that all time derivatives are zero. Setting all three differential equations to zero gives

\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 = 0 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= x_1 + x_3\,F(x_1) = 0 \\
\dot{x}_3 &= x_3\,F(x_1) = 0
\end{align}

The first equation gives $x_2=0$. By substituting the third equation into the second you get $x_1 + 0 = 0$ so $x_1=0$. Since $F(0)=0$ and $x_1=0$ at an equilibrium point we get $x_3\,F(x_1)=x_3\,0=0$, so $x_3$ can be anything.

Comment: What about the stability at and around that equilibrium point though?

Comment: @ChrisM You will have to perform linearization at the equilibrium points and check the eigenvalues of the system matrix. Stability might change between equilibrium points and would also require knowing more about $F()$, mainly the (sign of) partial derivative of it.